# How to attach a managed policy to a an IAM role using the CDK

Tags: python, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I'm try to create a service role for AWS CodeBuild.

I can create a role like this:

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as iam

role = iam.Role(
    self, 'CodebuildServiceRole',
    assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('codebuild.amazonaws.com'),
    max_session_duration=cdk.Duration.hours(1),
)
```

Now I need to attach the Amazon-provided `AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess` policy to the role.  How can I do this using the CDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the policy like this:

```py
AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess = iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name('AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess')
```

And attach it to your role like this:

```py
role.add_managed_policy(AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess)
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

According to [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.html#static-fromwbrawswbrmanagedwbrpolicywbrnamemanagedpolicyname), some policies have `prefixes` which needs to be included in the policy name supplied to the `from_aws_managed_policy_name`  function. Here is the code that worked for me in JavaScript.

```
iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole')
```

`service-role/` is the `prefix` in this case.

Comment: Reminding the prefix is a good point!